# how to create query to fetch records from json string

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb and our data is in json formate key value pair and i have a on key follower demographic and it's value is in json string formate. and i want to fetch records based on this string:

```
"followerDemographics":"{\"topfollowerDemographybyCities\":{\"Riau\":3.45,\"Jawa Timur\":6.9,\"Jawa Barat\":31.03,\"Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta\":6.9,\"Others\":48.28,\"Uttar Pradesh\":3.45},\"topfollowerDemographybyCountry\":{\"India-IN\":6.9,\"Philippines-PH\":3.45,\"Malaysia-MY\":3.45,\"Indonesia-ID\":82.76,\"United States-US\":3.45,\"Others\":0},\"InstagramId\":\"192198926\",\"gender\":{\"male\":26.246719160104988,\"female\":73.75328083989501}}"
```

i have already tried this:

```
     // Gender Ratio
      if (genderRatio === 'Male') {
         Influencer.find({}, async(err, influecner) => {
         const Influecner = influecner.map(async repo => {
           if(repo.followerDemographics){
            var x = repo.followerDemographics;
            x = x.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
            return {
                '_id':repo._id,
                'followerDemographics': JSON.parse(x)
              }
           }
          });
          Promise.all(Influecner).then((list) => {
            console.log(list, 'infinfinf');
          });

        });
        genderRatioQuery = {
          $and: [{ 'followerDemographics.gender.male': { $gte: parseInt(req.query.minGenderRatio) } },
            { 'followerDemographics.gender.male': { $lte: parseInt(req.query.maxGenderRatio) }} ],
        };
      }
```

this is the part of collection

```
"followerDemographics":"{\"topfollowerDemographybyCities\":{\"Riau\":3.45,\"Jawa Timur\":6.9,\"Jawa Barat\":31.03,\"Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta\":6.9,\"Others\":48.28,\"Uttar Pradesh\":3.45},\"topfollowerDemographybyCountry\":{\"India-IN\":6.9,\"Philippines-PH\":3.45,\"Malaysia-MY\":3.45,\"Indonesia-ID\":82.76,\"United States-US\":3.45,\"Others\":0},\"InstagramId\":\"192198926\",\"gender\":{\"male\":26.246719160104988,\"female\":73.75328083989501}}"
```

i have a serch filter in which i want to fetch records based on gender ratio.suppose when we click on male and set the range 20% to 70%
then i want to fetch all the records which is blongs to 20 to 70

Comment: This is definitely something that you should be able to achieve with MongoDB Map-Reduce and Aggregation Framework, probably using $regex or JSON.parse: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand which technology you use in your code, but if you write MongoDB JS script it would look similar to the following.

Let's say your db name is `geo_data` and your collection is `influencer` then the code going to look the following way using MapReduce function:

```js
var _db = db.getSiblingDB("geo_data");

// Parsing JSON field and filtering items we only need
mapFunc = function() {
    parsed = JSON.parse(this.followerDemographics);
    if (parsed.gender.male > 20 && parsed.gender.male < 70) {
        emit(this._id, this);
    }
}

// Returning all items
reduceFunc = function(id, items) {
    return { "result": items };
}

// Performing mapReduce here and the output will be in collection named `result`.
_db.influencer.mapReduce(mapFunc, reduceFunc, { out: "result" });

// Result collection in your db now contains all items filtered as you need
var items = _db.result.find();

// Showing result for testing purposes
items.forEach(function(x){
    print("Item: ");
    printjson(x)
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
i tried to do somthing like this. but when i tried to find records from result collection then i got this error:-
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: result is not defined.

Comment: If you share your code and tell in which framework you are trying to achieve this maybe I'll be able to help you

Comment: I am using nodejs framework. i have a search filter . there are many options and I am creating a query based on condition like if user want to fetch the records on bases of age then the query is:
 let query = { $and: [] };
 const age = { $and: [{ 'aboutMe.age': { $lte: new Date(req.query.age) } }] };
query.$and.push(age);
and if user want to fetch the records on the bases of age and gender. then the condition is:-
if (gender && gender !== 'both') {
  query.$and.push({ $and: [{ 'aboutMe.gender': gender }] });
}

Comment: and if user want to fetch the record based on genderRatio then how we can create a query when data is in json string format and push into the final query. 
after creating the final query i want to search recorde based on final query.
Influencer.find(query);